# Map oracle's type with hibernate

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, jpa

I got type declared in oracle

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE STATUS IS OBJECT
(
   status Number,
   tresc  Varchar2(32767)
)
```

And function

```
Function Test_Status return STATUS IS
Begin
  RETURN new STATUS(2,'Test');
End;
```

Is it possible to declare this type in hibernate and get it through hibernate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to implement a `org.hibernate.usertype.CompositeUserType` that reads this from JDBC into a Java object. You can then use the Java type in your models.

According to the Oracle JDBC driver documentation, the Java type will have to implement the `java.sql.SQLData` interface: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/sqlcustommapping.html

You can then use `java.sql.ResultSet#getObject(int, java.util.Map<java.lang.String,java.lang.Class<?>>)` in the user type to extract the object type from the result set and `java.sql.ResultSet#setObject(int, Object)` to set it on a prepared statement.