# Use hibernate to call stored procedure from Oracle

Tags: java, spring, oracle, hibernate, stored-procedures

I have to call stored procedure from oracle db.

Procedure have 11 IN fields  and 2 OUT.

One IN field is `slot DEFAULT null`.

Description for this field is:

```
create or replace TYPE slot
AS TABLE OF "XXX"."SLOT_REC"
```

This SLOT_REC is a table of 2 values:

```
create or replace TYPE slot_rec as OBJECT

         (

           a varchar2(14),

           b varchar2(2)

         );
```

I use StoredProcedureQuery and `registerStoredProcedureParameter(11, Slot.class, ParameterMode.IN)`

I created class: `class Slot implements UserType`
but have no idea how to implement this nested table.

StoredProcedureQuery works fine where IN parameteras are standard types or array of Strings. But here parameter 11 is Object which is nested and I can't manage it.

Welcome any help!

Comment: did you tried with passing an array ?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/66043935/412446 for an answer about how to handle composite data types.